# Extract one dimernsion of a 2D variant array to a string

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Similar to: [Convert Variant Array to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456244/convert-variant-array-to-string) - but the accepted answer there does not work in my case.

My code:

```
SQLStr = "SELECT lineID FROM alldata where asdf = '" & asdf & "'"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open SQLStr, conn, adOpenStatic

Dim arr
Dim arrString
rs.MoveFirst
arr = rs.GetRows
arrString = Join(arr, ", ")
```

after the statement `arr = rs.GetRows` executes, it has the following value in my console:

[image]

I'm trying to join these two values, separated by a `comma space` into a string, so the end results is:

`arrString = "25616, 99607"`

However, I get an `Invalid procedure call or argument` error when I run the `Join` line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the array being two dimensional.  I am looking in to testing it right now.

Comment: exactly - I couldn't figure out how to transpose it to a one-dimensional array either, which is why the code was breaking....  You can't join nothing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am certain there is a more elegant way to accomplish your task, I did write some code that appears to be running successfully.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestArray()

        Dim arr(0, 1) As Variant 'Mimic the structure of your array
        Dim arrString As String
        Dim sDelimiter As String
        Dim j As Long

        'Mimic the structure of your array
        arr(0, 0) = "25616"
        arr(0, 1) = "99607"

        sDelimiter = ", " 'Set your delimiter

        'Loop through the inner array
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
                'Concatenate the elements
                arrString = arrString & sDelimiter & arr(0, j)
        Next j

        'Remove the leading delimiter / cleanup
        arrString = Replace(arrString, sDelimiter, "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)

        MsgBox arrString

End Sub
```

The interesting code is from `sDelimiter = ", "` and down.

I could not figure out how to `Transpose` the array into a one-dimensional array (from an array of two dimensional arrays), so I decided to loop through the inner array and concatenate the values.

The concatenation results in an extra delimiter at the front of the list so there is a line that replaces that delimiter with nothing.

Comment: Wow, this is really nice.  I like how you solved the issue - building the string as `itself` + `the new stuff` in a loop.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As you are in Excel you can use `Index` to slice through and return a 1D array

```
 Dim arr(0, 2) As Variant

 arr(0, 0) = "25616"
 arr(0, 1) = "99607"
 arr(0, 2) = "12345"
 MsgBox Join(Application.Index(arr, 0), ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Join only accepts 1-d arrays. Here's a non looping way to get a recordset to a comma separated string.

```
Sub TestArray()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sArr As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open gsCON

    Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM InvoiceLine")

    rs.MoveFirst
    sArr = Join(Split(rs.GetString, vbTab), ", ")

    Debug.Print sArr

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

GetRows puts the data in the wrong row/column orientation. You could use `Application.Transpose` to get it right, but you still can't pass it to Join because it's 2D.

GetString returns a tab/lf delimited string. I split that on tabs, then rejoin it on comma-space, and it's good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 days ago there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32227677/4996248) which prompted me to write a function which I called `MultiSplit()` which took a string and 2 delimiters and split it into a 2-dimensional array. This current question requires a sort of inverse:

```
Function MultiJoin(A As Variant, Optional ItemDelimiter As String = ",", Optional RowDelimiter As String = ";") As String
    'assumes that A is a 2-dimensional array of strings
    Dim s As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lb1 As Long, lb2 As Long, ub1 As Long, ub2 As Long
    lb1 = LBound(A, 1)
    lb2 = LBound(A, 2)
    ub1 = UBound(A, 1)
    ub2 = UBound(A, 2)
    For i = lb1 To ub1
        For j = lb2 To ub2
            s = s & A(i, j) & IIf(j < ub2, ItemDelimiter, "")
        Next j
        s = s & IIf(i < ub1, RowDelimiter, "")
    Next i
    MultiJoin = s
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    ReDim A(0 To 0, 0 To 1)
    A(0, 0) = "25616"
    A(0, 1) = "99607"
    Debug.Print MultiJoin(A, ", ")
    ReDim A(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
    A(0, 0) = 1
    A(0, 1) = 2
    A(1, 0) = 3
    A(1, 1) = 4
    Debug.Print MultiJoin(A, " ", vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
25616, 99607
1 2
3 4
```